# Twilio Video in ReactJS - how do I access the room object after the initial setup?

Tags: reactjs, twilio, webrtc, twilio-video

My app is built in reactjs. There are a lot of "how tos" for the twilio video javascript sdk, but very little for people who are building in reactjs.

My problem is this: I have successfully implemented the construction and subscription of my users to a room. This is the process:

1. User 1 lands on user 2's profile, and decides to call. He presses the "call" button.
2. The server creates a call in the database, contacts Twilio with his info, and returns a twilio token to him.
3. He then connects to the room, publishes his local audio and video track to it, and waits the invitee
4. User 2's browser is informed of the call through a push notification from firebase messaging. He is sent a Twilio token from the server in that message, as well as information about the call and the room. His browser pulls up the "incoming call" page.
5. Assuming he answers, he begins publishing his own local audio and video tracks, and connects to the room.
6. The video and audio tracks of the other participant are attached to a couple react refs pointing to specific divs on the dom.

The video call is now progressing.

All this works well. However, my question is how do I access the actual room object at this point? Specifically, I want to mute the audio and video tracks based on input from the user. There are enable and disable methods in the Twilio library, but how to get to the tracks? The room creation and set up templates I have found online, which work, do not produce an object which can be modified, after the initial set up. All I get from let room = Video.connect... is a promise. If I use the Video.connect method AGAIN, it seems overkill - why contact Twilio again with my token when I already have a room in progress - and doesn't seem to work when I try.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I haven’t used Twilio video API but you should get the object as an parameter in `promise.then` callback which you can store

Comment: That did it. Thank you!